# Linq select new dynamic multi part List<>

Tags: c#, linq, refactoring

I have the following query I am playing about with:

```
public void FindAllRelatedProdsByParentCat(CategoryService categoryService, string parentCatName, bool isDeleted)
{
    List<Category> allCats = categoryService.FindAll(isDeleted).ToList();

    var results = (from a in allCats.Where(x => x.Name == parentCatName)
                   join b in allCats 
                   on a.CategoryId equals b.Parentcategory into children
                   select new 
                         { 
                           ParentId = a.CategoryId, 
                           ChildrenIds = children.Select(z => z.CategoryId) 
                         }).ToList();
}
```

Ideally what I would like is to flatten the select new statement into a generically typed list of Id objects. Currently I am having to compose an anonymous object with two properties to get what I want. Can one help me refactor this into one flat list? Is this do-able?

***UPDATES:*** What a Category Entity looks like:

```
public class Category : EntityBase
{
    public Category()
    {
        Products = new List<Product>();
    }

    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid? Parentcategory { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public Guid OrgId { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public virtual Organization Organization { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You'd like a list containing the `ParentId` and the `ChildrenIds`?

Comment: Yeah, thats exactly what I want. Just don't know how to refactor it.

Comment: What type is `allCats`? And why is there a `Join` on the same enumerable?

Comment: Can you add your `Category` type declaration?

Comment: @IbrarMumtaz I don't comprehend what you would want to obtain... do you want a single `List<int>` with all the `parent.CategoryId` and `child.CategoryId` together?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been made it more clearer. The Ids are Guids. And the join is on the same collection because some objects are marked by a parent id and some are not. This denotes a parent to child relationship. So @xanatos yes I would like a single list containing ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I comprehended what you want, but

```
var results = (from a in allCats.Where(x => x.Name == parentCatName)
               join b in allCats on a.CategoryId equals b.Parentcategory into children
               select new[] { a.CategoryId }.Concat(children.Select(z => z.CategoryId)))
              .SelectMany(x => x)
              .ToList();
```

I've tested it on Entity Framework 6.1.3 and it correctly generates a `UNION ALL` for the `select` line... and then uses a `CROSS APPLY` for the `SelectMany` (???)

Comment: = ), thats what I want. I did not know you could do that. Excellent that's what I am using also.

Comment: @IbrarMumtaz Note that I was missing a `)`. Code changed.

Comment: can you suggest a better title for my question so that it is more helpful to others??

Comment: @IbrarMumtaz *Put parent and children ids together with LINQ*?